# Glass PHP Quickstart project only works on localhost

Tags: php, apache, google-mirror-api, google-glass

Has anyone else experienced problems when implementing the Google Glass mirror-api quick start project on anything other than a local machine? The page is completely blank and returns a 500 error when moving to a remote server. Full LAMP stack installed.

If anyone would like more info, let me know. I've followed the instructions from Google exactly, and like I said, it's working locally.

Found this in the apache2 logs:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Google CurlIO client requires the CURL PHP extension' in /var/www/playground/glass/google-api-php-client/src/io/Google_CurlIO.php:47\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/playground/glass/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php(106): Google_CurlIO->__construct()\n#1 /var/www/playground/glass/mirror-client.php(35): Google_Client->__construct()\n#2 /var/www/playground/glass/index.php(25): get_google_api_client()\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/playground/glass/google-api-php-client/src/io/Google_CurlIO.php on line 47
```

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to migrate this to a DigitalOcean droplet, and I was immediatly greeted with 500 errors. Looking into the Apache2 error logs (no PHP errors, oddly enough), I found a PHP error being thrown:

```
Google CurlIO client requires the CURL PHP extension
```

For some reason, the PHP-curl extension was not installed by default on DigitalOcean's LAMP stack, nor installed on any of my other virtual servers (I spent two days attempting this on multiple environments). This was easily resolved by a `sudo apt-get install php5-curl` for anyone who's in the same boat.